# Asp.Net Core 3.1 MVC client side validation not working for views that are located in the Areas folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am creating a ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC application. I creating some logic, where the user can create a SellOffer. I want to add some client side validation. The problem is thaht when I enter invalid data nothing happens. I did some research and found out that it may have something to do with _ValidationScriptsPartial.cshtml. The views I want the validation on are located in the Areas folder, so I just copied the file to the Views folder in that Area, but it did not work. Here is my code.

This is the View.

```
@model SellOfferDTO

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h1>Create</h1>

<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ProductTitle" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="ProductTitle" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="ProductTitle" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ProductDescription" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="ProductDescription" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="ProductDescription" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ProductPrice" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="ProductPrice" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="ProductPrice" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group form-check">
                <label class="form-check-label">
                    <input class="form-check-input" asp-for="PriceIsNegotiable" /> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PriceIsNegotiable)
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group form-check">
                <label class="form-check-label">
                    <input class="form-check-input" asp-for="CanReciveBuyOffers" /> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CanReciveBuyOffers)
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Quantity" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Quantity" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Quantity" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to your Sell Offers</a>
</div>
```

This is my DTO. (Note: I plan on adding more validation atributes once I make it work)

```
   public int Id { get; set; }
    [StringLength(999999, ErrorMessage = "Products Title must be betwen 999999 and 3 in length", MinimumLength =3)]
    public string ProductTitle { get; set; }
    public string ProductDescription { get; set; }
    public decimal ProductPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalPrice { get; set; }
    public bool PriceIsNegotiable { get; set; }
    public bool CanReciveBuyOffers { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public string TagsStr { get; set; }
    public List<string> Tags { get; set; }
```

And this is the _ValidationScriptsPartial.cshtml

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

So my question comes down what fails my client side validation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a posible solution. I added this:

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

To the view and the validation seems to work just fine.